# PowerShell is slow to convert integers to strings

Tags: string, performance, powershell, int, type-conversion

I am writing a PowerShell script where many integers have to be converted to strings. I am using the `ToString` method to do this, as in:

```
$i = 5
$i.ToString()
```

Unfortunately, this seems to be very slow (I omitted the execution policy warning):

```
PS I:\ADCC\Scripting Performance> .\int_to_str.ps1
6.747561
PS I:\ADCC\Scripting Performance> .\int_to_str.py
0.37243021680382793
```

I am using PowerShell 2 and Python 3.

```
PS I:\ADCC\Scripting Performance> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1


PS I:\ADCC\Scripting Performance> python --version
Python 3.6.1
```

This is the contents of `int_to_str.ps1`:

```
(Measure-Command {
    ForEach($i in 1..1000000){
        $i.ToString()
    }
}).TotalSeconds
```

This is the contents of `int_to_str.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(1, 1000000):
    str(i)
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

As you can see, both scripts convert integers from 1 to 1,000,000 to strings. However, while PowerShell takes 6.75 seconds, Python only takes 0.37 seconds, making Python 18 times faster. In the actual PowerShell script that I am writing, it takes about three hours to convert all of the integers to strings, so an 18-fold speed improvement would be welcome.

Is there a faster way to convert an `int` to a `string` in PowerShell 2?

Comment: It's not the int to string conversion that's slow, it's likely the range operation (ie. python's `range()` is much faster in this context than PowerShell's `..` operator). What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am pulling some data from Active Directory that is returned as byte arrays, converting every byte to a integer string representation, and writing them to a CSV file. These byte arrays are particularly long. I'm not convinced that it is the range operation that's slow, though; `(Measure-Command { (5).ToString() }).TotalMilliseconds` still returns 0.0472, while `start = time.perf_counter()`, `str(5)`, `print(time.perf_counter() - start)` prints 1.995030623720074e-05.

Comment: Post your script if you want help making it run faster

Comment: For me on my machine that PowerShell (in 2.0) runs in ~3.6 seconds.. I shave a second of when I cast with `"$i"`. I agree that it might be better to see your actual implementation of code. In v5 it takes 1.5 seconds

Comment: The whole script is very, very long. I've used `Measure-Command` and `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to time the different sections of code, and I have narrowed the slow part down to the casting. Besides, regardless of my code, I still intend to ask what I asked--whether there is a faster way to cast integers to strings.

Comment: Converting byte arrays to their hexadecimal representations could be done far quicker, since a constant amount of memory can be allocated for it -- but I suppose that's no good. Optimizing PowerShell is like racing seahorses -- it's weird, it's messy, and the amount of success you can achieve is strongly limited by external factors. You have the right idea -- use another language. If you can't use Python, do the hairy bits in C#, those are easy to add to a PowerShell script with `Add-Type`.

Comment: To put this in other words -- you can't optimize `Int32.ToString()` in PowerShell, period. That's a basic .NET framework call, and replacing it with any kind of script would just be *slower*. If your bottleneck is those calls (likely not due to the call itself but the way PowerShell interacts with the call mechanism and the garbage collector), your only recourse is "don't do that" or "do less of that".

Comment: 1. PowerShell 2.0 is slower than the newer versions. 2. This loop is meaningless and can be rewritten as `[string[]]@(1..1000000)` 3. micro-optimizing in general is meaningless more often than it's not, especially in case of PowerShell which can use the power of .NET Framework built-ins. 4. Optimizing should be performed on the full (relevant part of) code; reworking the algo, things like memoizing; proper caching can speed up things 10, 100, 1000+ times.

Comment: what byte array field from AD are you using?  certificates? password? security descriptor?

Comment: @thepip3r It is the password.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I had not thought of writing some of the code in C#. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am not aware of a way to upgrade my version of PowerShell without upgrading Windows, which I unfortunately cannot do. I can try to memoize the integers and their string representations; I wonder whether that will actually be faster. There is pretty much no point in memoizing the byte arrays because they are almost all different.

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I can confirm that `"$i"` was faster than `$i.ToString()` on my machine.

Comment: @wecsam, IIRC I've been using .NET 4 and PS4.0 on XP 32-bit.

Comment: @wecsam - you can upgrade your version of powershell on the windows version you're currently on by upgrading the Management Framework.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395

Comment: @thepip3r Thank you, I had not been aware of that download.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, even in .NET (which is what you're using with PowerShell), here is a great article on the int->string conversion you care about:  http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-an-int-to-string.

As far as byte array conversions from AD, here is a test I did and with explicit casting to a `[string[]]`, I nearly always saw gains over using .tostring().  The gains ranged from 50% to equivalent but it was consistently faster:

```
$s = [adsisearcher]'(&(objectCategory=user)(samaccountname=mysam))'
$r = @($s.FindAll())

(Measure-Command {
    foreach ($b in $r[0].Properties.userpassword[0]) {
        $b.tostring()
    }
}).TotalSeconds

(Measure-Command {
    [string[]]$r[0].Properties.userpassword[0]
}).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I tried it with my 1,000,000 integers, and casting to `string[]` was five times faster.

Comment: To clarify, `[string[]](1..1000000)` was about five times faster than `ForEach($i in 1..1000000) { $i.ToString() }`.

Answer (score 6):

I have accepted @thepip3r's answer, but I want to highlight some other possible solutions from the comments on the question two things:

1. You can use `"$i"` instead of `$i.ToString()`. It is faster.
2. If you are on PowerShell 2, you can try downloading a newer version of the Windows Management Framework from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395

I will edit this if more solutions appear in the comments.